# How to execute java class on cron (Openshift)

Tags: java, web-applications, cron, openshift

I'm beginner in java developing and I'm facing the problem that someone of you probably solve very easily.

I try to create java webapp using openshift and one of its tasks is a background job which checks the text file on ftp server every hour and save some data to my database also placed on openshift.

I've done the script and it work properly, when I run it manually on eclipse localy. It's simple Java main class.

But how to configure the cron ?

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/src/main/java/. orbit.SLRDatabase
```

I wrote sth like this but an error occured because java class hasn't been found.

Is it right approach to do this task ? Or should I think about any better solution ? Please forgive me if I wrote something not quite properly, but i would be very grateful for all kind of help.

EDIT:

The problem was hidden in badly compiled class file (Thank you @yshavit). Finally I've made runnable jar (using eclipse) and run with the script shown below.

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/src/main/java/orbit/ldb.jar
```

Comment: Is ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR} set correctly? Many times a cron job won't set up the environment as expected which means it will be looking in /src/main/java, which likely does not exist. If you set the variable before the execute line, it may work.

Comment: src/main/java sounds like the path of your source code, not your compiled `.class` files. You should do more research into how to compile and run a Java class.

Comment: I've solved it ! Thank you @yshavit. Description in edited section.